# Help with falsetto

Tags: voice, falsetto

I can sing falsetto for short periods of time but it sounds terrible when I drag the note out. Can this be improved or am I stuck without falsetto?

Comment: Details on how it sounds and how you feel during it may help... like do you feel a choke or a break in you voice so on... edit your question accordingly and It will be easier for people to root out your issue :). welcome to the site btw.

Comment: Do you use any vibrato? How is your diction? Can you hold a note with the same 'pressure' or does it fluctuate in volume/tonal quality

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep from developing bad habits it is much safer to work with a vocal teacher one on one. Falsetto is natural. From your description it seems you are lacking support. Full falsetto is a developed voice however baritones seem to develop it more freely. Are you a tenor or baritone or bass?